# SDK development in multiple programming languages

Tags: c#, java, sdk, programming-languages

I am working to develop an SDK that will allow the users to use it and write code in C# or Java.

To achieve this most optimally, do I have to write the SDK in both languages? That would be a lot of code repetitions albeit in 2 different languages, and the maintenance overhead would be very high.

Are there efficient ways to solve this problem? What will happen if someday we think of adding a 3rd programming language support for the SDK?

Please note that I don't mind having an API instead of SDK. The idea is simple -- it's basically an interface or kit that would provide users to make simple calls to it to perform certain complex actions, all complexity being abstracted into the API or SDK.

Comment: Perhaps there are cross compiler. Write it in one language and compiles to other, but I doubt it.

Comment: It really depends on what you are allowing the developers to do against your SDK.  In other words, were is the separation between the SDK and components that the SDK is addressing?

Comment: Davin -- the exposure or the usages (or calls) to the API (SDK) will be limited to very high level functionality, and all details will be handled in the SDK. Given that, how do you suggest we can optimize the coding structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid code duplication, there are different options.

- you can create the base library in portable C++. C++ can then be interfaced in both Java (e.g. with JNI) and C# (e.g. with C++/CLI). That means that you can create a wrapper for both target languages using C++. This option is more difficult if you want to target more different operating systems.
- you can create the software as a service (e.g. SOAP or a simple json service). You can do that in the language you prefer and then create client applications in Java and C#.

It depends on your project, the people who will implement it and on your future goals what the best solution is.

Comment: I like your second idea. I am quite new to services, and hence this question. Can you please tell me what language the service can be so that the client applications can be written in Java and C# (and may be a third one later?)

Comment: The thing with services is that the server can be in any language, and the clients can be in the same or any other language. So if you choose to use services, choose the tools you are comfortable with in your preferred programming language. For C#, that will probably be WCF, for Java, that might be J2EE services.

Answer (score 0):

You could code the SDK in C++ and create java/C# wrapper classes to allow users to interface to the SDK

Also allows for easy extension to other languages as most languages allow you to utilise dlls wrote in C++.

Just an idea.

If you're interested read into DLL creation, the adapter pattern, JNI for java, not sure about C# I've not had that much experience